# MySQL occasional performance issues

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-8.0

I am currently working on system with MySQL DB and SpringBoot (Hibernate). Both are located on the same server. All tables use InnoDB. Although there are no slow queries (5+ seconds), there is periodically heavy load produced by mysql service, and I don't see the reason for this.

MySQL Server Version: 8.0.30
VM Spec: 256 GB RAM, 32 CPUs, 2 TB of SSD disk.
DB SIZE: 165 GB (+/- 5GB)

After much reading and tweaking, I have config which seems to work well for the current server resources, but MySQL is sometimes behaving very strange by tacking more than 50% of total CPUs and I really don't see why, so I am in a need of help, because this config is product based on pages and pages read on this stack, and maybe I have missed something.

**my.cnf** (all other sett):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=140G
innodb_log_file_size=40G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_buffer_size=256M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120

join_buffer_size=16M

long_query_time = 5

max_connections=301
max_user_connections = 270

wait_timeout=600
interactive_timeout=600

binlog_expire_logs_seconds=259200

tmp_table_size = 128M
max_heap_table_size = 128M

event_scheduler = OFF

slow_query_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/app-slow.log
slow_query_log=1
```

[SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS](https://pastebin.com/hFTW63dF)

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Lower to `long_query_time = 1` or maybe even `0.5`.  What is the value of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`?

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks for your reply. There are up to 350 used connections at max.

Comment: Hmmm... 350 is not possible with "max_connections=301"??

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant 250.

Comment: If there are 250 connections sitting idle, there should be no problem.  But if most of them are trying to do some big query, that is a problem.  And it will show up in the slowlog.